# Multiple key aggregation in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am new to Elastic Search and was exploring aggregation query. The documents I have are in the format -

```
{"name":"A",
     "class":"10th",
     "subjects":{
         "S1":92,
         "S2":92,
         "S3":92,
     }
}
```

We have about 40k such documents in our ES with the Subjects varying from student to student. The query to the system can be to aggregate all subject-wise scores for a given class. We tried to create a bucket aggregation query as explained in this [guide here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html), however, this generates a single bucket per document and in our understanding requires an explicit mention of every subject.

We want to system to generate subject wise aggregate for the data by executing a single aggregation query, the problem I face is that in our data the subjects could vary from student to student and we don't have a global list of subject keys.

We wrote the following script but this only works if we know all possible subjects.

GET student_data_v1_1/_search

```
{ "query" :
    {"match" : 
         { "class" : "' + query + '" }}, 
         "aggs" : { "my_buckets" : { "terms" : 
         { "field" : "subjects", "size":10000 },
         "aggregations": {"the_avg": 
                      {"avg": { "field": "subjects.value" }}} }},
          "size" : 0 }'
```

but this query only works for the document structure, but does not work multiple subjects are defined where we may not know the key-pair  -

```
{"name":"A",
     "class":"10th",
     "subjects":{
         "value":93
     }
}
```

An alternate form the document is present is that the subject is a list of dictionaries -

```
    {"name":"A",
     "class":"10th",
     "subjects":[
         {"S1":92},
         {"S2":92},
         {"S3":92},
     ]
}
```

Having an aggregation query to solve either of the 2 document formats would be helpful.
======EDITS======

After updating the document to hold weights for each subject -

```
        {
class": "10th",
   "subject": [
 {
   "name": "s1",
   "marks": 90,
   "weight":30
 },
 {
   "name": "s2",
  "marks": 80,
   "weight":70
 }
   ]}
```

I have updated the query to be -

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "class": "10th"
}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "subjects": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "scores"
      },    
      "aggs": {
        "subjects": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "subject.name"
      },
      "aggs" : { "weighted_grade": { "weighted_avg": { "value": { "field": "subjects.score" }, "weight": { "field": "subjects.weight" } } } }
      }
    }
  }
}
      },
      "size": 0
    }
```

but it throws the error-

```
{u'error': {u'col': 312,
u'line': 1,
u'reason': u'Unknown BaseAggregationBuilder [weighted_avg]',
u'root_cause': [{u'col': 312,
u'line': 1,
u'reason': u'Unknown BaseAggregationBuilder [weighted_avg]',
u'type': u'unknown_named_object_exception'}],
u'type': u'unknown_named_object_exception'},
u'status': 400}
```

Comment: Can you share the mapping of index in both the above cases. You are trying to apply aggregation on `subject.value` whereas `value` property doesn't exist under `subject`

Comment: @NishantSaini I have updated the question with the sample document with "value" property. It only works if we know all the possible key pairs or/and select only 1 key/document.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the required result I would suggest you to keep your index mapping as follows:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "class": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "subject": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "marks": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the mapping above I have created `subject` as `nested` type with two properties, `name` to hold subject name and `marks` to hold marks in the subject.

**Sample doc**:

```
{
  "class": "10th",
  "subject": [
    {
      "name": "s1",
      "marks": 90
    },
    {
      "name": "s2",
      "marks": 80
    }
  ]
}
```

Now you can use [nested aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html) and multilevel aggregation (i.e. aggregation inside aggregation). I used nested aggregation with `terms` aggregation for `subject.name` to get bucket containing all the available subjects. Then to get avg for each subject we add a child aggregation of `avg` to the `subjects` aggregation as below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "class": "10th"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "subjects": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "subject"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "subjects": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "subject.name"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "avg_score": {
              "avg": {
                "field": "subject.marks"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

*NOTE: I have added `"size" : 0` so that elastic doesn't return matching docs in the result. To include or exclude it depends totally on your use case.*

**Sample result**:

```
{
  "took": 25,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": [

    ]
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "subjects": {
      "doc_count": 6,
      "subjects": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "s1",
            "doc_count": 3,
            "avg_score": {
              "value": 80
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "s2",
            "doc_count": 2,
            "avg_score": {
              "value": 75
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "s3",
            "doc_count": 1,
            "avg_score": {
              "value": 80
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see the result contains buckets with `key` as subject name and `avg_score.value` as the avg of marks.

**UPDATE to include weighted_avg:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "class": "10th"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "subjects": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "subject"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "subjects": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "subject.name"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "avg_score": {
              "avg": {
                "field": "subject.marks"
              }
            },
            "weighted_grade": {
              "weighted_avg": {
                "value": {
                  "field": "subject.marks"
                },
                "weight": {
                  "field": "subject.weight"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Comment: thanks @nishantsaini this worked exactly as needed. I have added a "weight" key while ingesting the documents - 
{
  "class": "10th",
  "subject": [
    {
      "name": "s1",
      "marks": 90,
       "weight":30
    },
    {
      "name": "s2",
      "marks": 80,
       "weight":70
    }
  ]
}

but on updating the query to weighted average the score is throwing an error. I have updated the nested "aggs" to - 
"aggs" : { "weighted_grade": { "weighted_avg": { "value": { "field": "subjects.score" }, "weight": { "field": "subjects.weight" } } } }

Comment: I have updated the question to clearly show what I mean in the above comment

Comment: your update doesn't cover the mention of the weight that I have added in the edit update. I want to aggregate the marks based on weights assigned subject-wise.

Comment: Your query has  malformed json. Otherwise it seemed to be correct.

Comment: Updated the answer, please check. You can remove `avg_score` block completely from the query if you don't require it.

Comment: I continue to get this error - 
>{u'error': {u'col': 265,
            u'line': 1,
            u'reason': u'Unknown BaseAggregationBuilder [weighted_avg]',
            u'root_cause': [{u'col': 265,
                             u'line': 1,
                             u'reason': u'Unknown BaseAggregationBuilder [weighted_avg]',
                             u'type': u'unknown_named_object_exception'}],
            u'type': u'unknown_named_object_exception'},
 u'status': 400}

Comment: Can you copy paste your complete query as a seperate question. I or someone else can then look at it to find the issue.

Comment: done here [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53498595/weighted-average-for-nested-aggregation-in-elastic-search)