# Weighted Average for nested aggregation in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, compose-db

I am trying to obtain the weighted average by aggregating a nested list. 
Each document has details of a single student, and the subjects vary across each student and each subject has different weights.

I am trying to calculate the weighted average subject-wise.

My documents are of the form -

```
[{'class': '10th',
 'id': '1',
'subject': [{'marks': 60, 'name': 's1', 'weight': 30},
         {'marks': 80, 'name': 's2', 'weight': 70}]},
{'class': '11th',
 'id': '2',
'subject': [{'marks': 43, 'name': 's10', 'weight': 40},
         {'marks': 54, 'name': 's20', 'weight': 60}]},
{'class': '10th',
 'id': '3',
'subject': [{'marks': 43, 'name': 's1', 'weight': 20},
         {'marks': 54, 'name': 's20', 'weight': 80}]},
{'class': '10th',
 'id': '4',
'subject': [{'marks': 69, 'name': 's10', 'weight': 30},
         {'marks': 45, 'name': 's2', 'weight': 70}]}]
```

> Here s1,s10,s2,s20 are the subjects. For a given class, say "10th" I am trying to aggregate the weighted average.

The query I make is

```
GET students_try/_search
{
 "query": {
"match": {
  "class": "10th"
}
 },
"aggs": {
"subjects": {
  "nested": {
    "path": "subject"
  },
  "aggs": {
    "subjects": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "subject.name"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "avg_score": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "subject.marks"
          }
        },
        "weighted_grade": {
          "weighted_avg": {
            "value": {
              "field": "subject.marks"
            },
            "weight": {
              "field": "subject.weight"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
  },
 "size": 0
}
```

The error I get is -

```
{u'error': {u'col': 211,
        u'line': 1,
        u'reason': u'Unknown BaseAggregationBuilder [weighted_avg]',
        u'root_cause': [{u'col': 211,
                         u'line': 1,
                         u'reason': u'Unknown BaseAggregationBuilder [weighted_avg]',
                         u'type': u'unknown_named_object_exception'}],
        u'type': u'unknown_named_object_exception'},
 u'status': 400}
```

I am not sure what is causing the error.

Comment: What is the elasticsearch version? `weighted_avg` aggregation is available from elasticsearch version 6.4 and above and not in older versions.

Comment: ok, it seems my version is 6.2 - 
  "version": {
    "number": "6.2.2",
    "build_hash": "10b1edd",
    "build_date": "2018-02-16T19:01:30.685723Z",
    "build_snapshot": false,
    "lucene_version": "7.2.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version": "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version": "5.0.0"
  },

Comment: @NishantSaini can you point me to the source/link which details weighted_avg for version 6.4 and above. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes the weighted average as mentioned by Nishant only appears post 6.4 as mentioned in the section `A few others` in this [link](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-6-4-0-released) detailing 6.4 release

However I've come up with the below script using [Bucket Script Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-script-aggregation.html) which calculates the weighted avg for each and every bucket :

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "class": "10th"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "subjects": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "subject"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "subjects": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "subject.name.keyword"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "avg_score": {
              "avg": {
                "field": "subject.marks"
              }
            },
            "sum_score":{
              "sum_productOfMarksAndWeight": {
                "script": "doc['subject.marks'].value * doc['subject.weight'].value"
              }
            },
            "sum_weights": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "subject.weight"
              }
            },
            "weighted_avg":{
              "bucket_script": {
                "buckets_path": {
                  "sumScore": "sum_productOfMarksAndWeight",
                  "sumWeights": "sum_weights"
                },
                "script": "params.sumScore/params.sumWeights"
              }
            }
          }             
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you look at the above aggregation carefully, for every bucket I've calculated the `sum of weights` and `sum of product of weights and marks` using [Sum Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html) and then I've used these two aggregations to calculate the weighted aggregation.

Below is how your response appears. Notice that there is a caveat that you'd also see the `sum of weights` and `sum of product of weights and marks` in the aggregation result.

### Response

```
{
  "took": 12,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "subjects": {
      "doc_count": 6,
      "subjects": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "s1",
            "doc_count": 2,
            "sum_weights": {
              "value": 50
            },
            "sum_productOfMarksAndWeight": {
              "value": 2660
            },
            "avg_score": {
              "value": 51.5
            },
            "weighted_avg": {
              "value": 53.2
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "s2",
            "doc_count": 2,
            "sum_weights": {
              "value": 140
            },
            "sum_productOfMarksAndWeight": {
              "value": 8750
            },
            "avg_score": {
              "value": 62.5
            },
            "weighted_avg": {
              "value": 62.5
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "s10",
            "doc_count": 1,
            "sum_weights": {
              "value": 30
            },
            "sum_productOfMarksAndWeight": {
              "value": 2070
            },
            "avg_score": {
              "value": 69
            },
            "weighted_avg": {
              "value": 69
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "s20",
            "doc_count": 1,
            "sum_weights": {
              "value": 80
            },
            "sum_productOfMarksAndWeight": {
              "value": 4320
            },
            "avg_score": {
              "value": 54
            },
            "weighted_avg": {
              "value": 54
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this helps, let me know if it doesn't and if you think this solves what you are looking for, please go ahead and accept this answer ;-)